# How to get column names of Spark Row using java

Tags: java, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to convert a spark `dataframe` to `rdd` and apply a function using `map`.

In pyspark, we can fetch the values of corresponding column by converting the `Row` to dictionary (key being column name, value being the value of that column) as below

```
row_dict = Row.asDict()
val = row_dict['column1']    # I can access the value of any column
```

Now, in java, I am trying to do similar thing. I am getting the `Row` and I found that it has APIs to get the values based on index value

```
JavaRDD<Row> resultRdd = df.JavaRDD().map(x -> customFunction(x, customParam1, customParam2));

public static Row customFunction(Row row, Object o1, Object o2) {
    // need to access "column1" value from the row
    // how to get column name of each index if we have to use row.get(index)
}
```

How can I access the row values based on column names in java code?

Comment: ```row.getAs("column1")``` - this might be working. Still checking